# Creating challenges from homework.

Tags: discussion

Recently I've been posting a lot of challenges on the site. This is because I am in a class where the homework are programming challenges (Algorithm Class).

Is that OK? or should I stop posting them? I ask because I know this is not site for homework (Yes, the answers helps me to create better algorithms)

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/should-homework-be-allowed

Comment: Well, to prove that you have actually _done_ your homework prior to creating the challenge, you could self-answer it with your current solution.

Comment: If I were you, I'd wait until the assignment has been due and turned in before posting a challenge on it.

Comment: You should probably check with your teacher too, even if a golfed solution will probably get an awful grade, it could still be considered cheating depending on the university/school

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Depends

If you just come here and post "hi please help I am new to Python have to make program print 1 to 100 please give me code" then no. If you post an actual on-topic challenge-formatted question that adds something to the site, it doesn't really matter whether or not it was homework (unless your exact homework was to golf your code. I hope not).

Really, the two things we need to consider: is it on-topic, and do you deserve credit for it?

## Is it on-topic?

That depends on whether or not you made it on-topic. Whether or not it's on-topic has nothing to do with whether or not it's inspired by your homework or not, but just based on how you made it.

## Do you deserve credit for it?

Probably. Since your homework relies on certain algorithms that you can then adapt into code-golf challenges, it's really no different from creating a challenge from an already known sequence or a known algorithm. The point is that you still had to put forth the effort to extract the algorithms from the problem and adapt it into a PPCG-on-topic challenge.

Overall, as long as you didn't just copy-paste and it's on-topic, I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: However, you should always write your own code to solve these challenges.  Even if your homework is in, say, Python, and somebody posts a very nice python solution, don't copy their solution.

Comment: @Picard Definitely, I agree.

Comment: Homework won't require you to golf the code, but they may require an optimize to running.

Comment: @l4m2 on the contrary, I'd expect golfed code to receive a failing grade on most courses teaching a language. Something with very specific format requirement and golf not being compatible.

Comment: @JAD Agreed. Readability (often with comments) is emphasized, because the goal of a class is to prepare you for a job and practical usage. Code that you can't read a year after you wrote it isn't practical.

Comment: @mbomb007 and then there's code-golf code which I can't read a day after I wrote it :D

Comment: And to make sure it’s on-topic, make sure to use the Sandbox ;)